# Create global struct with dynamic member

Tags: c, struct, global-variables, ipc

I have something like the following:

```
struct t{
    char arr[variable_len];
    int i;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // set size of arr to length of argv[1]
}
```

Is there a way to do this?  I was originally just going to have arr be a pointer to an array and allocate the array separately, but this created massive issues due to the fact that I want to write this struct to a pipe (the pointer would get written and not the actual array).

Comment: `the pointer would get written and not the actual array`? If you can use `p` (the pointer) then can't you just do `*p` instead?

Comment: @stardust_ I could write the array separately (that would kill the point of using the struct), but if I were to do something like `write(pfd,some_struct,sizeof(some_struct))` there's no way for me to get the actual array pointed to by the member in the struct

Comment: You should think twice (and then twice more) before designing an IPC protocol that involves writing raw structs to a pipe (or file, or network socket), because you are then relying on the exact byte layout of the struct. Different compilers (or the same compiler invoked with different options) may make different choices about the amount of padding necessary in a struct. For example, in your sample above, if `arr[]` is 10 bytes long, will there be padding before `i`? How much? And how big is an `int` anyway?

Comment: You can solve that by adding **one more element to the struct that will hold the value of the array size**. That should be enough for all your requirements. And it will be a more proper implmentation

Comment: @stardust_ I'm not sure what you mean.  Something like `struct t{int i; char arr[i]};` and then setting i once I know how long the array msut be?

Comment: No no that's not possible. `struct t{int i; char* arr, int data_size};` and set data_size to the proper value when you allocate the space for `arr`. Then use that value when you need to copy or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside the lack of error checking, you could do the following...

```
struct t
{
    int i;
    int data_len;
    char arr[];
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int data_len = atoi( argv[1] );
    struct t* var;

    var = malloc( sizeof( struct t ) + data_len );
    var->data_len = data_len;

    // open a pipe and do cool stuff to var

    fwrite( var, sizeof( struct t ) + var->data_len, 1, output_pipe );

    free( var );
}
```

Comment: edited the original answer to account for writing the entire structure on a pipe as a contiguous block (which I missed when I read it the first time)

Comment: This is how I originally approached the problem, but I'm writing the struct to a pipe, and using a char* required two writes (one for the struct, one for the array pointed to by the struct), which defeated the point of the struct for this application.

Comment: See my edit -- I realized that after my first answer and modified it to meet that requirement

Comment: Is this "kosher" c?  Doesn't that require that the char arr always be last?  Also, what's the reason for switching from char *arr to char arr[]?

Comment: Yes... it is kosher C and it does require the array to be last in the structure. The reason for the `char arr[]` (with no array size) is to identify the array as a variable length array. The "size" of the structure is the size of all of the elements **except** the array itself (which for the purposes of a `sizeof()` call is 0)... which is why the malloc works... the size of everything except the array, plus the size of the array. So, `char arr[]` is an array of char of indeterminate length while `char* arr` is a pointer to char.

Comment: @KScottPiel, your vocabulary is not the right one. In standard C (since C99) this is called a "flexible array member". A variable length array (VLA) is different from that and is not allowed inside other structures, unions or other arrays.